# Regular Expression Matching Tags

Tags: regex

Whats the rule for match unwanted "outer" tags for xhtml?

Comment: What's the rule? What tags do you want to clean?

Comment: all tags which has another tag inside of it

Comment: @user3370932 that would clean the <Dis> and <ok> also

Comment: Why ? Dis and Ok tags have only strings. isnt that possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @user3370932 Don't. Just don't. Use an XML parser.

Comment: hmmm, at least any can explain, how  can i delete the tags which is contains > character

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2595658

Answer (score 1):

To match unwanted "outer" tags, so you can replace them with blank:

```
<(\w+)><.*?><\/\1>
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/THbMDL2GVr).